# Aggregate and Sort by a text field and concatenate other text fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, concatenation, aggregation, string-concatenation

In Elasticsearch, how does one **aggregate and sort** by a text field and concatenate field values of other text fields, joined by e.g. `;` ?

In concatenating I mean to concatenate values of the same field from all the aggregated documents, **not** values of different fields from the same document.

**Details**

I have small documents with fields gene, tag, annotation described as

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "annotations": {
      "properties": {
        "species": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "gene": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }  
          }
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "annotation": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are many entries per gene. That is, I have:

```
Gene  Tag   Annotation
----- ----- ---------------
A1BG  tag1  first gene
A2M   tag1  a-macroglobulin
A2M   tag2  second gene
BRCA1 tag1  breast cancer 1
BRCA1 tag3  important gene
```

I want to query these data, aggregate and sort by gene, and get something like this:

```
Gene   Tags        Annotations
------ ----------- -------------------------------
A1BG   tag1        first gene
A2M    tag1; tag2  a-macroglobulin; second gene
BRCA1  tag1; tag3  breast cancer 1; important gene
```

I can not find anything meaningful after googling for more than a day. Elasticsearch examples mostly show statistics e.g. counts, a few examples about concatenating fields from the same document but I could not find a way to concatenate the values of the same field. I tried to use `map` as well as something like this:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genes_agg" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['tag'].join('; ')",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't find anything because you're approaching this from a relational database perspective. Elasticsearch is built like a document store so you would basically put all the tags, annotations, etc for `BRCA1` in one document. I think you need to rethink your indexing strategy, not your querying strategy.

Comment: The point is that people will add annotations about genes over long periods of time. Periodically, we will need to see what has been accumulated and create reports. 
Thanks for the suggestion but could you please elaborate on how to implement that kind of approach? My guess is that then one would need to update existing indices every time annotations are added instead of creating new documents and try to aggregate them.
(Is it how they do e.g. Apache logs too?)

Comment: Exactly! I think you can either (1) update the documents and add the annotations or (2) add records each time and do the final concatenation after you receive the data from Elasticsearch.

The first gives you the benefit of the least amount of data over the wire and on disk but possible lots of updates on Elasticsearch (aka deletes + inserts) which might impact performance
The second means more data over the wire and on disk but less updates in the index.

Comment: It is still hard to believe that using scripts allows one to use `doc['tag']` and counting documents yet it is not possible to iterate through those documents.